# jquery pjax with php. no content at reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic, pjax

I try to use jquery pjax to load my contents in a div. this works fine, but if i reload the page i have no content. i think i need to put the page content in the else{ part, but i don't want to set the whole html in a php variable. how to fix this?

index.php:

```
<?php
    $title = 'Home';
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'){ ?>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>home</h1>
        </div>
    <?php echo "<title>{$title}</title>";
    }else{
        include 'wrapper.php';
    }
?>
```

wrapper.php:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style='margin-left:20px;'>
    <li><a href='index.php' data-pjax='content'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='page1.php' data-pjax='content'>Demo 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='page2.php' data-pjax='content'>Demo 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#content', { 
        fragment: '#content' 
    });
});
```

page1.php

```
<?php if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'){  ?>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
<?php } else{ include 'wrapper.php';} ?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'){
?>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
<?php }else{
    include 'wrapper.php';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only including the wrapper.php when the page is requested without PJAX (== the normal way). In wrapper.php the content is empty.

In wrapper.php you should include the correct page if the request origin is not PJAX:

First of all you should rename some files. Use index.php as the main lay-out file (what you intended to do with wrapper). Add the p as query param (which can be read true `$_GET` in PHP) to load pages when clicking links.

Create a file home.php which will be the default page loaded in `#content` at index.php.

index.php

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style='margin-left:20px;'>
    <li><a href='index.php' data-pjax='content'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='index.php?p=1' data-pjax='content'>Demo 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='index.php?p=2' data-pjax='content'>Demo 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <?php if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_AJAX'])) {
        if(!isset($_GET['p'])) {
            include('home.php');
        }
        else {
            include('page'.$_GET['p'].'.php');
        }
    } ?>
</div>
```

This is very simple example. In live applications this should be done in another way to protect the script against certain attacks.

I'm guessing you are a starter. Please take a look at CodeIgniter. It is a framework which has a lot of ready-to-use functions. It has proven to be 'easy' to learn...